# loading dataset where the dataadapter select command uses the IN clause with a subquery

Tags: select, dataadapter

I'm loading a subset of the parent records and the child records into a dataset then setting datarelations and foreignkeyconstraints, so when I am building the dataadapter select stmt for the child records, I must make sure that only the child records whose parent is present is loaded to avoid referential integrity errors.  Since the subset of the ParentTable has been loaded into a dataset I tried:

daChild = new OleDBDataAdapter(CreateOledbCommand("select * from Childtable where ChildKey in (ds.tables(""ParentTable""))",dconn))

But got an "undefined function 'ds.tables' in expression" error at runtime.

So, I tried to create a one column table to pass to the IN clause, like this:

Dim MyDataView as DataView = New DataView(ds.tables("ParentTable"))

Dim MyTempParentTable as DataTable = MyDataView.ToTable(False, "ParentKey")

daChild = New OleDbDataAdapter(CreateOledbCommand("select  *  from ChildTable where ChildKey in (MyTempParentTable)", dconn))

I checked in the debugger, and MyTempParentTable is, in fact, a one column table containing the key of the ParentTable.  I thought that the IN clause could take a one column datatable as valid input.  Apparently not, as I am getting a "No value given for one or more required parameters" error at runtime.

I'm just about out of ideas.  All my google searching came up with for the IN clause was something like IN (value1, value2, value3...)  and doesn't give any examples for the IN clause containing a more complex expression.
Can anyone clue me in on what I'm missing, or maybe a different way to accomplish this? I'm trying to get the IN clause to work because I'm thinking that it is the most efficient way to do this...  Maybe it's not...  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an answer to the question about why the IN clause didn't work, but just in case anybody else has this issue I will post my workaround.

I load the parent records as usual, but my dataadapter select stmt for the child records has a "WHERE 1=0" so that zero records are initially loaded. When a new parent record is displayed I then determine if the child records for that parent are already loaded into the dataset, if not, I load them in. Bottom line is that I don't pre-load the child records, rather, I load them "on demand".  This solution is working well for me.